# Why is $\|A_n -A\|=\sup |\alpha_i|$ in this proof

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question about the paragraph in [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=8KB-ALmOSagC&lpg=PA82&ots=WSTLBYd9ey&dq=compact%20operator%20diagonal%20sequence&pg=PA82#v=onepage&q&f=false) that starts with ''We look next ...'' (bottom half of this page).

Why is $\|A-A_n\| = \sup_{j > n}|\alpha_j|$? The operator norm is defined as $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|$. Why is this equal to the $\sup$ of the coefficients?

Comment: It is helpful if you explain what the operators $A$ and $A_n$ are, as well as what the $\alpha_j$'s are so that people can better help with this question without being dependent on the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an arbitrary $x \in H$.  Suppose $x = \sum_j x_j e_j$.  Note that
$$
\|(A - A_n)x\|^2 = \left\| \sum_{j > n} a_j x_j e_j\right\|^2= 
\sum_{j > n}|a_j|^2|x_j|^2\leq 
\sum_{j > n}(\sup_{j>n}|a_j|)^2|x_j^2| \leq
\left(\sup_{j>n}|a_j|\right)^2\sum_{j}|x_j|^2 \\
=  \left(\sup_{j>n}|a_j|\right)^2 \|x\|^2
$$
It remains to be shown that this upper-bound is sharp.